# Maps shows blank/nothing

Tags: android

My application shows blank google map on a fragment. I just call that fragment from MainActivity. I have searched/read on google, but none did help me at. I am not getting any error and I have used proper APIs Keys.
The following are my classes/mxls:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    private Button map_me;
    private Button bCordinates;
    public static Location mLastKnownLocation;
    private FusedLocationProviderClient mFusedLocationProviderClient;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mFusedLocationProviderClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);

        try {
            if (true) {
                Task<Location> locationResult = mFusedLocationProviderClient.getLastLocation();
                locationResult.addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<Location>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Location> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {

                            //Get the Location of the current device
                            mLastKnownLocation = task.getResult();
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        } catch (SecurityException e)  {
            Log.e("Exception: %s", e.getMessage());
        }

        bCordinates = (Button)findViewById(R.id.bcordinates);
        bCordinates.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view)
            {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),""+mLastKnownLocation.getLatitude()+" , " +
                        " "+mLastKnownLocation.getLongitude(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });


        map_me = (Button)findViewById(R.id.bmap);
        map_me.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
                android.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                MyMapFragment myMapFragment = new MyMapFragment();
                fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragment_container, myMapFragment);
                fragmentTransaction.commit();
              }
        });
    }
}
```

---

```
public class MyMapFragment extends Fragment implements OnMapReadyCallback {


private GoogleMap googleMap;
private MapView mapView;
private View view;
private FusedLocationProviderClient mFusedLocationProviderClient;

public MyMapFragment() {

}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.map_layout, container, false);
    return view;
}


@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    mapView = (MapView) getView().findViewById(R.id.map);
    if(mapView!=null)
    {
        mapView.onCreate(null);
        mapView.onResume();
        mapView.getMapAsync(this);
    }
}

@Override
public void onMapReady(final GoogleMap mGoogleMap) {
    {
        googleMap = mGoogleMap;
        LatLng mLatLng = new LatLng(mLastKnownLocation.getLatitude(),
                mLastKnownLocation.getLongitude());

        googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(mLatLng).title("You're here"));
        googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(mLatLng,15));
        mapView.onResume();
    }
}
}
```

map fragment layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MyMapFragment">

    <com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/map"
        />

</FrameLayout>
```

main activity layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.bdushimi.android2.MainActivity"
    >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bmap"
        android:layout_width="88dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="MAP Me!"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.067"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="32dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btext"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TEXT ME!"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="32dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.464" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bcordinates"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Cordinates"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="32dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="28dp"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.949"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="333dp"
        android:layout_height="370dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="125dp"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.514"></LinearLayout>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Please, help me to find out what I am doing wrong.

Comment: put your logcat here

Comment: Does the device where you're testing have a working Internet connection?

Comment: Check the logcat, you might be missing the API key or device ID registration.

Comment: @diegoveloper, @ HTMLlama. the following are the logcat :         
11-13 23:31:10.082 8405-17846/com.bdushimi.android2 W/libEGL: [ANDROID_RECORDABLE] format: 2                                                                                                               .

Comment: @m0skit0, yet it does have a working internet connection.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use MapFragment or SupportMapFragment in your map layout xml file according to your usability.

For now :
Replace :

with :

```
<fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/headerLayout"
        tools:context="com.dxs.rnf.winwin.main.ui.fragments.DashboardMapFragment"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"/>
```

**[Note : Also check your GOOGLE_API_KEY](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/signup)**